# MSBuild Change reference path at Build?

Tags: msbuild

This MSBuild starts to be a rally pain.
I got a project that reference a .dll, but the BuildServer don't find it and I get 'Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly'

So, my project reference this .dll as the one located in something like d:\common\DllPath\mydll.dll, and in the projectfile mycsproj.csproj it says HintPath.. \ .. \ .. \ .. \ .. \ ..\DllPath\mydll.dll

So, everything works just fine when I build it on my workstation, AND if I open it with VS2012 at the Build-server. (At the server, the paths is actually also D: \ but that's just a coincidence.)

But when I try to build it as a build definition it fails. It looks like it builds it at C:\Builds\43\Myapp, and I guess when the  "SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}" Considered ".. \ .. \ .. \ .. \ .. \ ..\DllPath\mydll.dll", but it didn't exist." is in the log it tries to find the .dll at c: folder.

How can I get it to point at the 'right' relative directory? For me it is the same partition as the project itself.
 Is it in Build-definitions, or do I have to change something in the .csproj-file? (In the .csproj it is already a relative path, and I don't want to change that.)

Comment: "This MSBuild starts to be a rally pain." in my experience when that happens, you are probably doing it wrong. HintPaths like that are begging for problems. So either make sure the directory structure on your server is the same, or use a property/environment variable to configure the hintpath properly (someting like mockinterface's answer).

Comment: We got exactly the same structure in dev and Build environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the location of your project the anchor and locate everything relative to `MSBuildProjectDirectory`.

The `MSBuildProjectDirectory` property is more extensively discussed in [How can I get current directory in msbuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111256/how-can-i-get-current-directory-in-msbuild-script).

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the xml in the csproj file.

See the first URL below.

[How to add a linked file to a csproj file with MSBuild. (3.5 Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867117/how-to-add-a-linked-file-to-a-csproj-file-with-msbuild-3-5-framework)

[FTP Credentials for MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Communication.Ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377738/ftp-credentials-for-msbuild-extensionpack-communication-ftp)

It's better to have thing consistent between your dev and build environment.
But most don't think about this until down the road.

So Xml-Update could be your friend to alter the HintPath.

Comment: Thnx, I will look at that. (Actually, We got exactly the same structure in dev and Build environment. Both pointing to D..TFS..Procect.. and so on.)

Comment: Then another suggestion is to have a "getter" to pull the files to the relative directory in your build scripts.  Basically, a down-load files and them them in the correct relative directory.  These files ~could exist in source-control, but a more hip way is to deal with a binary repository like nuget.

Answer (score 0):

See and click up Wolf5's answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666618/csproj-multiple-hint-paths-for-an-assembly).

The directory structure most likely has the project files one level lower than the working directory.  This how my projects usually are.  The solution is to add an extra HintPath in your project file with whatever path MsBuild needs.  For example I have this in my projects:

```
<Reference Include="Blah.Namespace.Path.SomeReference, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath  Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\bin\Debug\SomeReference.dll')">..\..\..\..\..\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\bin\Debug\SomeReference.dll</HintPath>
  <HintPath  Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\bin\Debug\SomeReference.dll')">..\..\..\..\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\bin\Debug\SomeReference.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```